# Why cant I get the text boxes to POST/GET when I submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is the dom:

[image: Chrome snapshot]

This is how I am submitting:

```
            function createOrderItems(){
                showCustomPanel(" Creating Order Items ");
                $("#order_items")[0].submit();
                return false;
            }
```

Here you can see that the text field isnt getting picked up:

[image: No text fields are posting]

Comment: It doesn't contain a name, use name="somename" to send it with the form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need name attribute on it to get it included in params

Answer (score 0):

To add more detail to the answer already given, If you don't give the input a name then it has nothing to assign the information to that is entered into the text box.

Think of it like a variable

= "stuff"; wont do anything

this = "stuff"; will store stuff into this. Then you can use that information later.

Not really how it works on the back end but it is a good way of understanding it.